# How can I wrap a Mocha or Jest test suite in a Node.js AsyncLocalStorage.run?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, jestjs, automated-tests, mocha.js

I have a test suite for a Node.js+express.js application that requires database access using Sequelize. My previous experience was in Python+Django. In Django, there is a nice TestCase class that wraps each test in a transaction; the transaction is rolled back automatically at the end of each test. This is a good idea to ensure data-wise isolation among tests.

I want to replicate the same effect using Mocha or Jest. I get a feeling that there should be a way using Node.js (v16)'s `AsyncLocalStorage`, but I just can't get it to work.

My guess at the gist of it is something like this:

- instantiate an AsyncLocalStorage in a module, and export it.
- in my test file, import the AsyncLocalStorage instance;
  _ call Mocha's `describe()`;
- inside the callback for `describe`, create a Sequelize transaction;
- inside the callback for the Sequelize transaction:

  - store the transaction in the AsyncLocalStorage instance
  - call Mocha's `before` hook; then, inside the callback for the before hook:

    - create a Sequelize transaction checkpoint
    - insert some fixture rows into the database using that checkpoint
  - call Mocha's `after` book; then, inside the callback for the after hook:

    - rollback the checkpoint
  - call Mocha's `it` a couple of times to define each test; inside each test:

    - call some application functions that I want to test; each of these functions will:

      - import the AsyncLocalStorage instance and try to find a transaction in it
      - if a transaction is found in AsyncLocalStorage, create another checkpoint on it and use it
      - otherwise start a new transaction

Doing so would allow the application functions to see the fixture data that I inserted in Mocha's `before` hook. And then the checkpoint rollback in Mocha's `after` hook would just clean everything up. I wouldn't have to write my own SQL `DELETE` queries, for example, and clean up would always be correct. I wouldn't have to worry about one test suite accidentally leaving data that contaminates the next test suite (which would cause a lot of head scratching).

I tried two different ways, but none of them worked (the tests wouldn't actually get run).

Attempt 1:

```js
import { QueryTypes, Transaction } from 'sequelize';

import { applicationFunction1, applicationFunction2 } from '../src/blabla';
import { sequelize, transactionStorage } from '../src/infrastructure/orm';
import { insertFixtureSQL } from './fixture'

const map = new Map<string, Transaction>();

describe('My super awesome test suite', async function() {
  // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-this,babel/no-invalid-this
  const mocha = this;

  // `transactionStorage` is an AsyncLocalStorage instance
  // start an AsyncLocalStorage run by giving it the map;
  // other async functions down the chain should be able to retrieve the same map;
  await transactionStorage.run(map, async () => {
    // `sequelize` is a `Sequelize` instance
    await sequelize.transaction(async (transaction) => {
      // put the transaction in the map
      map.set('transaction', transaction);

      mocha.beforeEach(async () => {
        // Create a checkpoint
        const checkpoint = await sequelize.transaction({ transaction });

        // Replace the transaction with the checkpoint (which itself is a sequelize Transaction instance)
        map.set('transaction', checkpoint);

        // Insert fixture data using the checkpoint;
        // `insertFixtureSQL` is a string that contains an SQL INSERT statement.
        await sequelize.query(insertFixtureSQL, { type: QueryTypes.INSERT, raw: true, transaction: checkpoint });
      });
      mocha.afterEach(async () => {
        const checkpoint = map.get('transaction') as Transaction;

        // If I just rollback the checkpoint, everything shall be cleaned up
        await checkpoint.rollback();
      });

      it('My awesome test 1', async () => {
        // inside `applicationFunction1()`, it will try to find the transaction from the
        // `transactionStorage`;
        // if found, it will create another checkpoint on it and use it;
        // otherwise, it will create a new Sequelize transaction.
        await applicationFunction1();
      });

      it('My awesome test 2', async () => {
        // inside `applicationFunction2()`, it will try to find the transaction from the
        // `transactionStorage`;
        // if found, it will create another checkpoint on it and use it;
        // otherwise, it will create a new Sequelize transaction.
        await applicationFunction2();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Attempt 2:

```js
import { QueryTypes, Transaction } from 'sequelize';

import { applicationFunction1, applicationFunction2 } from '../src/blabla';
import { sequelize, transactionStorage } from '../src/infrastructure/orm';
import { insertFixtureSQL } from './fixture'

const map = new Map<string, Transaction>();

// `transactionStorage` is an AsyncLocalStorage instance
// start an AsyncLocalStorage run by giving it the map;
// other async functions down the chain should be able to retrieve the same map;
transactionStorage.run(map, async () => {
  // `sequelize` is a `Sequelize` instance
  await sequelize.transaction(async (transaction) => {
    // put the transaction in the map
    map.set('transaction', transaction);

    describe('My super awesome test suite', async function() {
      this.beforeEach(async () => {
        // Create a checkpoint
        const checkpoint = await sequelize.transaction({ transaction });

        // Replace the transaction with the checkpoint (which itself is a sequelize Transaction instance)
        map.set('transaction', checkpoint);

        // Insert fixture data using the checkpoint;
        // `insertFixtureSQL` is a string that contains an SQL INSERT statement.
        await sequelize.query(insertFixtureSQL, { type: QueryTypes.INSERT, raw: true, transaction: checkpoint });
      });
      this.afterEach(async () => {
        const checkpoint = map.get('transaction') as Transaction;

        // If I just rollback the checkpoint, everything shall be cleaned up
        await checkpoint.rollback();
      });

      it('My awesome test 1', async () => {
        // inside `applicationFunction1()`, it will try to find the transaction from the
        // `transactionStorage`;
        // if found, it will create another checkpoint on it and use it;
        // otherwise, it will create a new Sequelize transaction.
        await applicationFunction1();
      });

      it('My awesome test 2', async () => {
        // inside `applicationFunction2()`, it will try to find the transaction from the
        // `transactionStorage`;
        // if found, it will create another checkpoint on it and use it;
        // otherwise, it will create a new Sequelize transaction.
        await applicationFunction2();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The difference between the two attempts is the order of the wrapping:

- Attempt 1:

  1. Mocha's `describe()`
  2. `transactionStorage.run()`
  3. `sequelize.transaction()`
  4. Mocha's `beforeEach`/`afterEach`/`it`
- Attempt 2:

  1. `transactionStorage.run()`
  2. `sequelize.transaction()`
  3. Mocha's `describe()`
  4. Mocha's `beforeEach`/`afterEach`/`it`

What happens when I try to run my test suite:

```
  0 passing (1ms)

info:    Executing (55fc411e-2a51-4095-9279-aec3942dc818): START TRANSACTION;
info:    Executing (55fc411e-2a51-4095-9279-aec3942dc818): COMMIT;
```

Which means it didn’t actually find any test to run.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening in your case is:

1. Test Suite starts and calls your wrappers
2. Your wrappers start connecting to database but wont finish in current loop tick, they are `async`
3. At the end of loop tick Test Suite doesn't see any tests and quits

The problem is asynchronous initialization of your tests. I'm not sure if it is possible to create tests asynchronously.
I would put asynchronous preparations to `beforeAll`.
And if you need to run tests inside of `AsyncLocalStorage.run` use a mock.

I've just faced similar problem and solved it with dependency injection of MockAsyncLocalStorage.
My code uses AsyncLocalStorage and I provide it slightly modified as if everything is inside `AsyncLocalStorage.run`

```
class MockAsyncLocalStorage extends AsyncLocalStorage<object> {
  private globalStore = {};

  getStore(): object {
    const store = super.getStore();
    if (!store) {
      return this.globalStore;
    }
    return store
  }
}
```

I use Nestjs so dependency injection in tests looks like this:

```
  const moduleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [App],
  })
    .overrideProvider("AsyncLocalStorage")
    .useValue(new MockAsyncLocalStorage())
    .compile();
```